# group_by and arrange the rows accroding to their value in a column

Tags: r

I have seen some similar questions in here but still using similar codes I do not arrive at the desired output.

This is my data...

```
structure(list(Condition = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), Primary = c("love", 
"love", "love", "love", "love", "place", "place", "place", "place", 
"place", "park", "park", "park", "park", "park", "hill", "hill", 
"hill", "hill", "hill", "pool", "pool", "pool", "pool", "pool", 
"bike", "bike", "bike", "bike", "bike"), Secondary = c("trail", 
"surprise", "elegant", "instinct", "person", "car", "amid", "sentiment", 
"family", "sensation", "affect", "effective", "ground", "hug", 
"punch", "maze", "amicable", "fierce", "measure", "thankful", 
"like", "smile", "wish", "ask", "humble", "stress", "happiness", 
"flat", "bed", "sky"), Score = c(0.09, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.3, 0.12, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.2, 0.11, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.18, 
0.07, 0.07, 0.05, 0.05, 0.25, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.25, 0.14, 
0.11, 0.07, 0.06), Condition2 = c("CM", "CM", "CL", "CL", "CL", 
"CM", "CM", "CM", "CL", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CL", "CM", NA, 
"CL", "CM", "CL", "CM", NA, "CM", "CM", "CL", "CL", "CM", "CM", 
"CM", "CL", "CL"), place = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), preference = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", NA, "2", "1", 
"2", "1", NA, "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For example, I have a chunk of data that looks like this...

```
 Condition Primary Secondary     Score Condition2 place preference
    1       place   car          0.30     CM        1    1
    1       place   amid         0.12     CM        2    1
    1       place   sentiment    0.03     CM        3    1
    1       place   family       0.03     CL        4    2
    1       place   sensation    0.03     CM        5    1
```

What I want to do is to order the 'preference' column in an ascending manner. So I need this chunk to look like this...

```
 Condition Primary Secondary     Score Condition2 place preference
    1       place   car          0.30     CM        1    1
    1       place   amid         0.12     CM        2    1
    1       place   sentiment    0.03     CM        3    1
    1       place   sensation    0.03     CM        5    1
    1       place   family       0.03     CL        4    2
```

I tried using this code

```
newData <- my_data %>% 
  arrange(preference) %>% 
  group_by(Primary) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

However, when I execute that code I get this result...

```
Condition Primary Secondary     Score Condition2 place preference
 1 1         love    trail      0.09     CM        1     1         
 2 1         love    surprise   0.07     CM        2     1         
 3 1         place   car        0.3      CM        1     1         
 4 1         place   amid       0.12     CM        2     1         
 5 1         place   sentiment  0.03     CM        3     1         
 6 1         place   sensation  0.03     CM        5     1         
 7 2         park    affect     0.2      CM        1     1         
 8 2         park    effective  0.11     CM        2     1         
 9 2         park    ground     0.05     CM        3     1         
10 2         park    punch      0.05     CM        5     1
```

So the words get mixed up. It is like the group_by is not working correctly. So what I want is to group_by primary and then order the preference column in an ascending manner so when I ungroup I have the result that I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of your `Primary` column doesn't matter you could `arrange` by both columns at once without a `group_by`:

```r
set.seed <- 42

library(dplyr)

my_data <- data.frame(
  Primary = sample(c("love", "place", "park"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  preference = sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
) 

my_data %>% 
  arrange(Primary, preference)
#>    Primary preference
#> 1     love          1
#> 2     love          2
#> 3     love          2
#> 4     park          1
#> 5     park          1
#> 6     park          1
#> 7     park          2
#> 8    place          1
#> 9    place          2
#> 10   place          2
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you provided doesn't have the preference column. However, this should work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Primary) %>% 
  arrange(Primary, preference)
```

Edit: More information

Whenever you want to make operation on groups, you need to specify the groups before doing it, oterhwise it won't work. In the code you provided, you first arrange the rows by `preference`, then you group by `Primary`. You first need to say you group by `Primary`, then all the operation will occure within each group (here you arrange by `preference`).

Comment: Hello, I just edited the data. Now the primary column is there. However, I tried to use the code as you share it and I still get the same result, words get mixed up.

Comment: See the edit @Ajrmand, it looks like the answer proposed by @stefan. I let mine for the explanation about `group_by`